# buildroot-qemu and qr4 examples

Tags: graphics, linux-kernel, qemu, buildroot

I am trying to run the qt4 examples in my qemu (x86_64) setup using the images generated by buildroot . I enabled framebuffer support and VGA-16 color graphics support in the kernel configuratonand I am able to see the 18bit boot logo. However, when I try to run the qt examples, it says there is no support for 16 bit graphic driver.

What kernel module support should I enable to resolve this?

Comment: Did you enable the fb backend of Qt (BR2_PACKAGE_QT_GFX_LINUXFB)? Did you enable all pixel depths?

Comment: @Arnout , it is already enabled.